# JS : Modules import/export won't work ES6

Tags: javascript

Im coding for a school project and they dropped this code, that is working fine.
But they want us to bundle those javascript files into one file, using **imports/exports**.
It looks EASY but it's NOT.

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Basic routing</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <a href="#">Home</a>
    <a href="#pagelist">PageList</a>
    <a href="#pagelist/borderlands">PageList borderlands</a>

    <section id="pageContent">Choisissez un lien</section>

    <script src="js/Home.js"></script>
    <script src="js/PageList.js"></script>
    <script src="js/PageDetail.js"></script>
    <script src="js/routes.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>

  // then i'll use <script src="./dist/bundle.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

**src/js/Home.js**

```
const Home = (argument = "") => {
 console.log("Page List", argument);
};
export default Home
```

**src/js/PageDetail.js**

```
const PageDetail = (argument) => {
  const preparePage = () => {
    cleanedArgument = argument.replace(/\s+/g, "-");


    const fetchGame = (url, argument) => {
      let finalURL = url + argument;

      fetch(`${finalURL}`)
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((response) => {
          let { name, released, description } = response;

          let articleDOM = document.querySelector(".page-detail .article");

          articleDOM.querySelector("h1.title").innerHTML = name;
          articleDOM.querySelector("p.release-date span").innerHTML = released;
          articleDOM.querySelector("p.description").innerHTML = description;
        });
    };

    fetchGame(`https://api.rawg.io/api/games?key=4a7bd6f3d4314002babc4e422c08c2e6& ${cleanedArgument}`);
  };

  const render = () => {
    pageContent.innerHTML = `
      <section class="page-detail">
        <div class="article">
          <h1 class="title"></h1>
          <p class="release-date">Release date : <span></span></p>
          <p class="description"></p>
        </div>
      </section>
    `;

    preparePage();
  };

  render();
};
export default PageDetail
```

**src/js/PageList.js**

```
const PageList = (argument = "") => {
  const preparePage = () => {
    cleanedArgument = argument.replace(/\s+/g, "-");
    let articles = "";

    const fetchList = (url, argument) => {
      let finalURL = url;
      if (argument) {
        finalURL = url + "?search=" + argument;
      }

      fetch(`${finalURL}`)
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((response) => {
          response.results.forEach((article) => {
            articles += `
                  <div class="cardGame">
                    <h1>${article.name}</h1>
                    <h2>${article.released}</h2>
                    <a href = "#pagedetail/${article.id}">${article.id}</a>
                  </div>
                `;
          });
          document.querySelector(".page-list .articles").innerHTML = articles;
        });
    };

    fetchList(`https://api.rawg.io/api/games?key=4a7bd6f3d4314002babc4e422c08c2e6& ${cleanedArgument}`);
  };

  const render = () => {
    pageContent.innerHTML = `
      <section class="page-list">
        <div class="articles">...loading</div>
      </section>
    `;

    preparePage();
  };

  render();
};
export default PageList
```

**src/js/routes.js**

```
const routes = {
  "": Home,
  "pagelist": PageList,
  "pagedetail": PageDetail,
};
export default routes
```

**src/js/index.js**

```
import Home from './Home'
Home() // trying to invoke them one by one.. but it's not working 
import PageList from './PageList'
PageList() // 
import PageDetail from './PageDetail'
PageDetail() // 
import routes from './routes'
routes()

let pageArgument;

const setRoute = () => {
  let path = window.location.hash.substring(1).split("/");
  pageArgument = path[1] || "";

  var pageContent = document.getElementById("pageContent");
  routes[path[0]](pageArgument);
  return true;
};

window.addEventListener("hashchange", () => setRoute());
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => setRoute());
```

Now if I take all the code from all the files and put them in one file.
It works. But i don't understand how to do and why it's so hard for something thats looks really easy.

**in-one-file, its working but I must use imports/exports, so I cannot use that !**

```
const Home = (argument = "") => {
  console.log("Batman", argument);
};

const PageDetail = (argument) => {
  const preparePage = () => {
    cleanedArgument = argument.replace(/\s+/g, "-");


    const fetchGame = (url, argument) => {
      let finalURL = url + argument;

      fetch(`${finalURL}`)
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((response) => {
          let { name, released, description } = response;

          let articleDOM = document.querySelector(".page-detail .article");

          articleDOM.querySelector("h1.title").innerHTML = name;
          articleDOM.querySelector("p.release-date span").innerHTML = released;
          articleDOM.querySelector("p.description").innerHTML = description;
        });
    };

    fetchGame(`https://api.rawg.io/api/games?key=4a7bd6f3d4314002babc4e422c08c2e6& ${cleanedArgument}`);
  };

  const render = () => {
    pageContent.innerHTML = `
      <section class="page-detail">
        <div class="article">
          <h1 class="title"></h1>
          <p class="release-date">Release date : <span></span></p>
          <p class="description"></p>
        </div>
      </section>
    `;

    preparePage();
  };

  render();
};

const PageList = (argument = "") => {
  const preparePage = () => {
    cleanedArgument = argument.replace(/\s+/g, "-");
    let articles = "";

    const fetchList = (url, argument) => {
      let finalURL = url;
      if (argument) {
        finalURL = url + "?search=" + argument;
      }

      fetch(`${finalURL}`)
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((response) => {
          response.results.forEach((article) => {
            articles += `
                  <div class="cardGame">
                    <h1>${article.name}</h1>
                    <h2>${article.released}</h2>
                    <a href = "#pagedetail/${article.id}">${article.id}</a>
                  </div>
                `;
          });
          document.querySelector(".page-list .articles").innerHTML = articles;
        });
    };

    fetchList(`https://api.rawg.io/api/games?key=4a7bd6f3d4314002babc4e422c08c2e6& ${cleanedArgument}`);
  };

  const render = () => {
    pageContent.innerHTML = `
      <section class="page-list">
        <div class="articles">...loading</div>
      </section>
    `;

    preparePage();
  };

  render();
};

const routes = {
  "": Home,
  "pagelist": PageList,
  "pagedetail": PageDetail,
};

let pageArgument;

const setRoute = () => {
  let path = window.location.hash.substring(1).split("/");
  pageArgument = path[1] || "";

  var pageContent = document.getElementById("pageContent");
  routes[path[0]](pageArgument);
  return true;
};

window.addEventListener("hashchange", () => setRoute());
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => setRoute());
```

Answer (score 1):

Your combined file and your individual files clearly contain different code: In `src/js/index.js` you are calling `Home` and claim it doesn't work. In the single file you are not calling `Home`. So why do you call `Home`?

`Home`, `PageList` and `PageDetail` are not needed in `src/js/index.js`. They are used in `src/js/routes.js`, so that's where they should be imported:

```
import Home from './Home'
import PageList from './PageList'
import PageDetail from './PageDetail'

const routes = {
  "": Home,
  "pagelist": PageList,
  "pagedetail": PageDetail,
};
export default routes
```

`routes` is required in `src/js/index.js` but you don't need to call it (and can't because it's not a function, it's an object). It's accessed further below `routes[path[0]](pageArgument);`. So all you have to do is import it:

```
import routes from './routes'

let pageArgument;
...
```

---

It's not clear what you do with your HTML, but you'd either only include the `index.js` file as a module or you would include the bundle file, but certainly not all files individually.

Comment: Thanks for answering.
It says "Home is not defined" now.
I think I should export my Home into PageList & PageDetail, but then I know I'll face more errors ( I've tried already ).

Comment: Where is the error thrown? You are not referencing `Home` anywhere else. *" I think I should export my Home into PageList & PageDetail"* Why do you think that? Are you accessing `Home` there?

Comment: routes.js:3 Uncaught ReferenceError: Home is not defined
    at routes.js:3
I'll try to export PageList & PageDetail there, then more errors coming for sure I've tried that already.
Sorry if I seem arsh or lame, Im new and have never been struggling like this before.

Comment: See my update to the question. Without knowing how/when/where the file `routes.js` is processed I can only guess. If you haven't added the `import` statements to `routes.js` then do that because that's part of the fix.

Comment: Aight i've reach back that point where the error message is too big for me to handle.
'''
Uncaught ReferenceError: cleanedArgument is not defined
    at preparePage (PageList.js:5)
    at render (PageList.js:40)
    at Object.PageList [as pagelist] (PageList.js:43)
    at setRoute (app.js:27)
    at app.js:33
'''

Comment: You forgot to declare `cleanedArguments`. It should be `const cleanedArguments = ...` at the beginning of those functions (i.e. add `const`). Modules are always *strict*, so any variable has to be declared.